# How to update a page after it's loaded?

Tags: javascript, node.js, push-notification

I have a webpage that's for a fund raiser, and I'd like to update the amount raised live. So if a user is looking at the total raised, and somewhere else another user donates, then the first user would see the amount tick up and change to the updated amount.

I have a CouchDB for a database and Lambdas using Node.js running. How can I set this up?

Comment: you can achieve it by either polling the server from your front end or use websockets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a well known software development pattern. It's usually achieved by using "push" or "pull" approach.

In a "pull" approach a client constantly asking for data from backend. In your particular scenario it could be a timer on a page that at specified interval polls server for data and updates page if needed.

In a "push" approach backend "pushes" changes to client(s) when they become available. Web sockets  would do the job in your particular case but implementing it is much more complicated than a "pull" approach.

Comment: Thanks so much. I think I'm looking for a push method. Web sockets might work. Let me read up on websockets on AWS and Lambda.

Comment: Yeah, pull does seem much simpler. Long polling if I'm not mistaken is what this was called?

Comment: Long polling is a different story. I am not sure if you need it at all. Long polling was a hack in a "pull" approach to make it look like a "push" approach. It was at the time when there was no technical way of implementing "push" approach differently. Now we have websockets and "long polling" is obsolete IMHO

Comment: So how do we do the pull method these days?

Comment: Just a regular javascript timer updating page let's say every minute will do the job.